# Can a connected finite-dimensional manifold have cardinality $>2^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

> Can a connected finite-dimensional manifold have cardinality $>2^{\aleph_0}$?

I know that if we either impose the condition "Hausdorff" or "second countable", the assertion is false. What if we drop these two common requirements?

Comment: The [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) is the closest thing I can think of, except if you tried to extend it further, then the very next point you would introduce, namely $(\omega_1, 0)$, is not the limit of any increasing sequence. So it would no longer be locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. Plus, the long line (and its extensions) are all Haussdorff.

Comment: I am not familiar with long line. Is it connected, finite-dimensional? What is its cardinality?

Comment: Oh it has cardinality same has real.

Comment: It is connected, one-dimensional, and has the same cardinality as the reals, but it "longer" than the real line in the sense that every countable sequence is bounded. In other words, no countable sequence ever comes close to the "end" in the way for instance $a_n = n$ does for the real line.

Comment: @Arthur: But the cardinality of the long line is $2^{\aleph_0}$, at least assuming the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What I meant with my first comment was that assuming the axiom of choice (or more specifically that there is an ordinal $\beta$ such that $|\beta|> 2^{\aleph_0}$), you may extend the construction of the long line until you get to a cardinality greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$. That does not work for reasons also pointed out in my comment (the result cannot be called a manifold).

Comment: @Arthur: Right. (As far as "more specifically" choice assumptions, well, this is inaccurate and very tricky to pin down exactly. But it suffices to say that it is consistent that the long line has cardinality strictly greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$.)

Comment: If you demand that the manifolds are Hausdorff, then [no](http://mathoverflow.net/q/67962/40804).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are connected (non-Hausdorff, non-second countable) manifolds of arbitrarily large cardinality.  For instance, let $S$ be any discrete space and let $X$ be the quotient of $\mathbb{R}\times S$ by the equivalence relation that identifies $(a,s)$ with $(a,t)$ whenever $a\neq 0$.  (This is like the well-known "line with two origins", except with $|S|$ origins instead of just two.)  Then $X$ is connected and locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, but the points $[0,s]$ are distinct for all $s\in S$, so $|X|\geq|S|$.  In fact, $|X|=|S|+2^{\aleph_0}$, so you can get $X$ to have any cardinality $\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

(We can also make $X$ a smooth or even real-analytic manifold by taking the maps $\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}\times\{s\}\to\mathbb{R}\times S\to X$ as charts for each $s\in S$.)